# How to remove or edit the pluralization for comments and likes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rails-i18n, pluralize

I am new to rails, and i am working on a rtl website! I am trying to fix the pluralization in comment.count and get_upvotes.size to be replaced by the other language words. I have heard that I can do it with Rails Internationalization (I18n) but I could not find a clear answer to my question.

Here's my code in the show.html.erb page:

```
#post_show
    %h1= @post.title
    %p.username
        before
        = time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at)
    .clearfix
        .post_image_description
            = image_tag @post.image.url(:medium)
            .description= simple_format(@post.description)
        .post_data
            = link_to "Project link", @post.link, class: "btn btn-warning btn-block"
            = link_to like_post_path(@post), method: :get, class: "data" do
                %i.fa.fa-check
                = pluralize(@post.get_upvotes.size, "Like")
            %p.data
                %i.fa.fa-comments.o
                = pluralize(@post.comments.count, "Comment")
            - if @post.user == current_user
                = link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post), class: "data"
                = link_to "Delete", post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Sure?" },class: "data"
```

Now all I need is to cancel the pluralization so when 2 comments or more shows up it does not pluralize and change to comments. Instead it stays the same as comment

I would appreciate the help. Let me know if more information is needed! Thanks

Comment: Don't use the pluralize method.  `= "#{@post.comments.count} Comment"`

Comment: What to replace it by?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to translate `Like` and `Comment` using I18n while also keeping the pluralization?

In your views, you need to change:

`pluralize(@post.get_upvotes.size, t('models.posts.votes'))`
`pluralize(@post.comments.count, t('models.posts.comments'))`

Then in `config/locales/en.yml`

```
en:
  models:
    posts:
      votes: Like
      comments: Comment
```

Then in `config/locales/ro.yml`

```
ro:
  models:
    posts:
      votes: Aprecieri
      comments: Comentarii
```

Rails will automatically take the appropriate Language 'pack' based on whatever variable you set.

So for example, if you wished to pass the language in the URL like so: `www.myapp.com?lang=en` Rails will use the `en.yml` locales. Whereas `www.myapp.com?lang=ro`will use the `ro.yml` locales.

It's up to you on how you choose the language.

Comment: This sounds great! However, the langauge i am using is arabic. When there is 0 or 2 and more comments there is still an S for pluralization at the end of the word. For example, ###s. I do not want the S to appear with the arabic word.

Comment: I don't think that's possible out of the box. You'll most likely have to create a helper that doesn't pluralize your string if language is arabic.

Comment: Ok. How about if i use the string without the pluralizer `{post.comments.count} Comment` ?

Comment: Well, it will work. But you will have, most likely, strings like: `3 Comment` or `0 Comment` .. Why is it that you don't want pluralization if the language is Arabic?

Comment: The thing is that I don't know how to create a helper that doesn't pluralize the string. I'm pretty new to rails.